# Linux without update window

Tags: updates

Everytime I start my Ubuntu laptop there's an update window in the upper left corner. It talks about updating applications.

I did update and I did set it to only apply security updates. The update window will just be always there after boot. What is it doing? It can't have new updates every time.

Is there something like Ubuntu without the update window? Like any other linux distribution for surfing the net?

Comment: Your question is asking for recommendations for Linux distributions that aren't Ubuntu. This is [off-topic](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) for multiple reasons.  First, only Ubuntu is supported on this site.  Second, questions soliciting opinions are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Under the Settings (gear icon), Notifications, turn off the software updater switch notifications.